# How to make CMake 'FILE' command dependent on TARGET or OUTPUT?

Tags: cmake

I've got some `add_custom_command()` stuff in a CMake build to do some things after building an elf file target: convert it to srec, fill various areas with 0xFF and create a binary image, generate a CRC and get the size of the image.  `add_custom_command()` can have DEPENDS, making it run only when the elf file is regenerated, which is great.

What I also want to do is the create a new file using FILE() that contains the binary filename, crc, and size (maybe in simple JSON format), but the documentation implies that I can't do this file activity *after* the things I mention above have happened.

```
# This command creates the FF-filled binary file.  It uses objcopy to create the srec
# file to operate on.
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ThreadingApp.bin filled.srec
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ThreadingApp.elf
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} ARGS -O srec ThreadingApp.elf ThreadingApp.srec
    COMMAND srec_cat.exe ThreadingApp.srec -offset - -minimum-addr ThreadingApp.srec
            −fill 0xFF -over ThreadingApp.srec -o filled.srec
    COMMAND srec_cat.exe filled.srec -o ThreadingApp.bin -binary
    )

# This command creates the CRC
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT crc.out size.out
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY filled.srec
    COMMAND srec_cat.exe filled.srec -crc32-b-e 0x08100000 -crop 0x08100000 0x08100004 -o - -hex-dump > crc.out
    COMMAND srec_info.exe filled.srec > size.out
    )

file(
    WRITE ThreadingApp.json

    )
```

Looking at the synopsis of 'FILE', I don't see how I can make this happen only after my custom commands have already run.  Any suggestions on how to achieve this within CMake?  My alternative is to write a separate Python script to execute within an `add_custom_command` to create the json file.

```
Reading
  file(READ <filename> <out-var> [...])
  file(STRINGS <filename> <out-var> [...])
  file(<HASH> <filename> <out-var>)
  file(TIMESTAMP <filename> <out-var> [...])

Writing
  file({WRITE | APPEND} <filename> <content>...)
  file({TOUCH | TOUCH_NOCREATE} [<file>...])
  file(GENERATE OUTPUT <output-file> [...])

Filesystem
  file({GLOB | GLOB_RECURSE} <out-var> [...] [<globbing-expr>...])
  file(RENAME <oldname> <newname>)
  file({REMOVE | REMOVE_RECURSE } [<files>...])
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY [<dir>...])
  file({COPY | INSTALL} <file>... DESTINATION <dir> [...])
  file(SIZE <filename> <out-var>)
  file(READ_SYMLINK <linkname> <out-var>)
  file(CREATE_LINK <original> <linkname> [...])

Path Conversion
  file(RELATIVE_PATH <out-var> <directory> <file>)
  file({TO_CMAKE_PATH | TO_NATIVE_PATH} <path> <out-var>)

Transfer
  file(DOWNLOAD <url> <file> [...])
  file(UPLOAD <file> <url> [...])

Locking
  file(LOCK <path> [...])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike to `add_custom_command`, which COMMAND is executed on *build* stage, `FILE()` is executed **immediately**, at *configuration* stage when `CMakeLists.txt` is processed.

You may however put `FILE()` invocation into separate CMake script, and run this script with `add_custom_command`. With that approach the script with `FILE()` will be executed at *build* stage of your project, and you may use OUTPUT or TARGET option:

```
# File: my_script.cmake
file(...)

# File: CMakeLists.txt:
add_custom_command(OUTPUT | TARGET ...
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script.cmake"
    )
```

Aside from demonstrated CMake [scripting mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script) (`cmake -P`) there is a [command line mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) (`cmake -E`), which can perform basic operations **without** needing to write a **script**.

```
# File: CMakeLists.txt:
add_custom_command(OUTPUT | TARGET ...
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "<content-of-the-file>" > "</path/to/file>"
    )
```

See also that question about redirecting output in `add_custom_command`: [How to redirect the output of a CMake custom command to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582344/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-a-cmake-custom-command-to-a-file).

Comment: Is this really the only way to achieve this? It feels really dumb to do it.

Comment: CMake is **not a build tool**. After *configuration stage* is complete, CMake creates files for the **actual** build tool (Makefile, Visual Studio, etc.). So at the *build stage* CMake language is not supported directly.

Comment: Ok sure, but then isn't there a way in CMake to generate a Makefile that writes a file as we want? We can do it by add_custom_command and calling some command line tool to do it, but then it won't be portable. I guess what you suggest gets around that but it feels super hacky for such a simple task.

Comment: By itself, Make cannot create and write files, it should execute **external utilities** for doing that. *Scripting mode* of CMake (`cmake -P <...>`) is one of such utility, and it is very portable across the platforms. I don't understand why you oppose this approach. There is also a [command line mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) of CMake, which perfoms simple actions without needing to write a script.

Comment: Well I don't oppose it, it just feels needlessly complex. I am not saying there *is* a better way, it just seemed like there should be. The command line mode is helpful though, saves having to have a whole other cmake script lying around just to create a file.

Comment: Ok, so your first comment was a hint to "search harder" and it seems to achieve its goal: I have updated my answer about using a CMake command line mode. This way is actually looks nicer and even fits for original author intentions. Note sure why I forgot about this way when initially wrote the answer. Thanks for remind me that!

Comment: To run another cmake with `-e` option in `add_custom_command`, you may need to add [`VERBATIM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) for escaping `echo` command string properly, otherwise the inner cmake command (and the `echo` command) will fail silently.